# How to "port" Java2D code to LWJGL

Tags: opengl, java, rendering, lwjgl

I've been following some game tutorials on youtube and developed a custom engine using Java (Graphics2D, BufferStrategy and such).

I have a class "Surface", which represents any 2D object (image, animation, sprite, text, graph, tiled map, height map, etc). All surfaces have some generic properties and a BufferedImage where the current state is drawn, and passed to the renderer when needed.

Everything works fine, but i wanted to try something "better" so now i have a new project using LWJGL 3 and... i'm totally lost.
I know OpenGL and Graphics2D are parallel universes, but at this moment i just want to adapt the existing code to the new libraries.

How can i create a target surface for 2D drawing, which can receive pixels from different sources and drawing methods, using modern OpenGL/LWJGL?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to make a class that replicates Javas Graphics class in LWJGL.

For textures you can write your own LWJGL wrapper or use Slick 2D

Comment: Thanks, but can you elaborate your answer?